# Can't execute command to set environment variables in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-atlas

I have seen the following links to execute multiple commands in `docker-compose` file:

- [Docker-Compose + Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938508/docker-compose-command)
- [Using Docker-Compose, how to execute multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063907/using-docker-compose-how-to-execute-multiple-commands)
- [docker-compose run multiple commands for a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767496/docker-compose-run-multiple-commands-for-a-service)

which tell us how to execute multiple commands in docker-compose file (also in the docker container).

In order to run [sburn/apache-atlas](https://github.com/sburn/docker-apache-atlas/) image properly, I have to set some environment variables which exists in `/opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/conf/atlas-env.sh` directory.

I have tried the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  atlas:
    image: sburn/apache-atlas
    container_name: atlas
    ports:
      - "21000:21000"
    volumes:
      - "./bash_script:/app"
    command: bash -c "
      source ./opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/conf/atlas-env.sh
      && chmod 777 /app/import-hive.sh
      && /opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/bin/atlas_start.py
      "
```

Unfortunately, the first command (I mean `source ./opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/conf/atlas-env.sh`) doesn't work. It doesn't have any error but the environment variables such as JAVA_HOME aren't set.

**How are you checking that the variables are not set?**

1. Run `Docker exec -it atlas bash` in the terminal.
2. Run `set` in the terminal. It shows all the environment variables.
3. Check whether the environment variables are set or not.

Comment: How are you checking that the variables are not set? Can you provide a [mcve] including the file being sourced, and command used to check if the variables are set?

Comment: @BMitch I have added how I check the environment variables

Comment: As Arman answered, `docker exec` is the wrong way to check. `source` modifies a single bash shell, and `docker exec` will start a different command in the container that doesn't share any environment with the container's pid 1 process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question involves a lot of stuff, if you can narrow it down people can help better. Here are my suggestions to debug it:

```sh
bash -exc "
    echo home1=$JAVA_HOME
    source ./opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/conf/atlas-env.sh
    echo home2=$JAVA_HOME
    chmod 777 /app/import-hive.sh
    echo home3=$JAVA_HOME
    /opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/bin/atlas_start.py
"
```

If `JAVA_HOME` is never set, there's something wrong with `.sh` file, either you fix that file or manually set it with

```
export JAVA_ENV=/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

Or defining it in your compose yaml file.

---

Also the way you're checking for env vars is wrong, running `Docker exec -it atlas bash`  won't run in the same bash as `bash -c "source ./opt/apache-a..."`

Answer (score 0):

to set enviroment variables you must set this:

```
environment:
  - JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
  - OTHER_VARIABLE=example
```

Or you can set your variables on Dockerfile with:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME="Your variable"
ENV OTHER_VARIABLE="example"
```

If you want execute ./opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/conf/atlas-env.sh script at the container start because this script have all environments that you need, you can include it on entrypoint or Dockerfile with CMD exec

Example:

```
FROM: source_image
RUN source ./opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/conf/atlas-env.sh
ENTRYPOINT []
```

To execute commands from your docker-compose try this:

```
command: sh -c "source ./opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/conf/atlas-env.sh"
```

Regards

Sources: [docker-compose, run a script after container has started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615751/docker-compose-run-a-script-after-container-has-started)

Comment: what's the difference between `sh` and `bash`?  As I wrote, I have tried `command: sh -c "source ./opt/apache-atlas-2.1.0/conf/atlas-env.sh"` but it doesn't work!

Comment: You can't `RUN` a command to set persistent environment variables.  `source` isn't a standard shell command, but `.` is and has the same effect.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have also tried `.` but it doesn't work.